# IBM Cloud how to increase concurent requests limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-cloud

I add/update action as follows:

```
ibmcloud wsk action update action_name --timeout 600000 --kind python-jessie:3 ./zips/zip_name.zip
```

But when I execute the action I get very very often an error as follows:

```
{'error': 'Too many concurrent requests in flight (count: 60, allowed: 60).'}
```

Is there any way to increase that number?

Answer (score 0):

this is an unusual situation, since the default concurrency limit is 1000 vs 60. I order to raise that back up to the default, can you please open a support ticket in the IBM Cloud UI, we'll then work this out from our end.

Comment: I've tried but I've got an error that it cant be processed. The exact error is: "There was an error creating your case. Try again later."

Comment: It's created. The Case ID is: CS0175697

Comment: Hi. Can you help me. Its still 60.

Comment: sure -- can you please DM me on the slack account described here https://openwhisk.apache.org/slack.html ?